# Paypal IPN: is the payer_email always present for purchases?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Exactly as the title says... Can I rely on payer_email always being present in an IPN message when receiving money?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be receiving it for incoming transactions . You can check for detailed information here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB070DUI .